# How do libraries with classes work?

Tags: c++, libraries

When learning C++ in school we never really talked about how to build libraries, so sorry for my rudimentary understanding. 
From what I've read online, it seems like a library is just a collection of code that is already compiled, and then there is a `.h` file that lists what functions are accessible in that library.

For example when I `#include <cmath>` I can now call `sin(x)` without having access to the cmath code to compile it. My question is if this works with classes that have data in them.

So can I create a library

```
//AccumulatorLibrary.h
class Accumulator
{
public:
    int num;
    int increment() {num++};
    void otherFunctions(); //otherFunctions defined in the .lib file
}
```

And then call it

```
//Main
#include "AccumulatorLibrary.h"
#include <stdio>
int main()
{
    Accumulator A(0); //initalize num to 0
    Accumulator B(7); //initalize num to 7
    cout<<A.increment;
    cout<<B.increment;
    cout<<A.increment;
}
```

and get an output of `1 8 2` ?

In summary, if I figure out how to put a bunch of classes into a library file can I access any data I want to, as long as that data has an access function in the `.h` file?

Or a more basic question, do a `.h` and `.lib` file work exactly the same as regular c++ code except that it doesn't have to be compiled when you use it, and you don't have access to the code in the `.lib` file?

Comment: In short, yes. A library file is basically a collection of object files, and you link object files when you build your program "normally". Libraries work in the exact same way.

Comment: you have many errors in that code, it's better to actually use a compiler to validate our thinking...

Comment: Ya, sorry. I realize that code won't run, I was just trying to type enough to hopefully get the question across.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From what I've read online, it seems like a library is just a collection of code that is already compiled, and then there is a .h file that lists what functions are accessible in that library.

Correct.

> My question is if this works with classes that have data in them.

It does. A lot of C++ libraries expose classes and have their code precompiled in a library.

> Or a more basic question, do a .h and .lib file work exactly the same as regular c++ code except that it doesn't have to be compiled when you use it...

Wait, wait. .h files still contain C++ code (declarations and sometimes even inline implementations). .lib files are dynamically linked libraries. They're the result of the compilation (and linkage) of the C++ source files.

> ...and you don't have access to the code in the .lib file?

You do have access to it: open it using a disassembler. It just won't be C++ anymore.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, skilled reverse engineers do (and I agree, meanwhile I'm not a skilled reverse engineer). Ask the chef of your local pentest group, see what he responds ;-)

Comment: but that's not "the code", that's "different code that does the same thing"

Comment: @MooingDuck That's some code, anyway... Let's not have a debate on this :)

Answer (score 1):

> From what I've read online, it seems like a library is just a
>   collection of code that is already compiled

Yes and no.

To me, a "library" is a body of code (one or more header (`.h)` files and zero, one, or more source (`.cpp`) files), without the `main()` function, that can be independently compiled and linked (except for `main()`).

A library may be available in various mechanisms:

- Available as source: Here you have to compile the library along with your application. Examples are C++ standard template library, Boost C++ libraries, a library that you or your colleague wrote, a library that you downloaded from sourceforge etc. (Caveat: Sometimes source-based libraries can be pre-compiled in a system as a compilation optimization.)

  Note that, being available as source means you can read it, but not necessarily modify it.
- Available as binary: Here, the library is already compiled and perhaps available in your system. Examples are C standard library, C++ standard library, C math library etc. From the question, it sounds like that this is the one you are referring to.

> then there is a .h file that lists what functions are accessible in
>   that library.

True, that is the case for a C library. For C++, the concept is naturally extended to include the classes and (public) member functions.

> In summary, if I figure out how to put a bunch of classes into a
>   library file can I access any data I want to, as long as that data has
>   an access function in the .h file?

Yes!

> Or a more basic question, do a .h and .lib file work exactly the same
>   as regular c++ code except that it doesn't have to be compiled when
>   you use it, and you don't have access to the code in the .lib file?

A library follows the same rules of C++, the only difference as mentioned above, is that it does not have a `main()` function.

Whether you need to compile or not depends on the way it is available to you (see above).

For many libraries, you have access to the source code (see above).

Following is the full code for your example:

```
// AccumulatorLibrary.h
class Accumulator {
  public:
    Accumulator( int x ) : num( x ) {}    // ctor with initializer
    int increment() {num++};
    int get() const;
    void set( int x );
  private:
    int num;
};
// AccumulatorLibrary.cpp
int Accumulator::get() const { return num; }
int Accumulator::set( int x ) { num = x; }

// Usercode.cpp
#include "AccumulatorLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Accumulator A(0); //initalize num to 0
    Accumulator B(7); //initalize num to 7

    A.increment();
    cout << A.get() << endl;        // print 1

    B.increment();
    cout << B.get() << endl;        // print 8

    A.increment();
    cout << A.get() << endl;        // print 2
}
```